# How to show coordinate from center of maps in textview?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I want to get coordinate from center of maps and showing coordinate in textview, when I scroll maps, coordinate in textview change. This code didn't work, textview just showing coordinate my current location although I scroll maps.

**My Kotlin code:**

```
class ActivityMaps :
        AppCompatActivity(),
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener{
...
override fun onLocationChanged(newLocation: Location?) {
        val latLng = LatLng(newLocation!!.latitude, newLocation.longitude)
        mMaps!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
        mMaps!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18f))
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this)
        }

       mMaps.setOnCameraIdleListener(GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
            val centerPos : LatLng = mMapsNPlotBng.cameraPosition.target

            tv_latitute!!.text = centerPos.latitude.toString()
            tv_longitude!!.text = centerPos.longitude.toString()

        })
    }
...
}
```

Please help me and Thank's.

Comment: Do you want your textview to be always in center of map? Means even of map moves, textview should remain at center of map?

Answer (score 0):

In your layout xml file you have to take one marker at the center of map. then implement setOnCameraChangeListener and in onCameraChange method you can find latlong using `cameraPosition.target`